# How To use super to default implementation in an interface

Tags: java, java-8

It will awesome if I can apply a refer to a default implementation to the interface in the following program using `super`. Like `Alpha.super.reset()` so, plz tell us where this statement will be use.

```
interface Alpha {
  default void reset() {
    System.out.println("This is alpha version of default");
  }
}

interface Beta {
  default void reset() {
    System.out.println("This is beta version of default");
  }
}

class MyClass implements Alpha, Beta {
  void display() {
    System.out.println("This is not default");
  }
}

class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    MyClass ob = new MyClass();
    ob.reset();
    ob.display();
  }  
}
```

For example if we want to use the beta version of `reset()` method, then we have to extend one of them two interfaces. For example : `interface Beta extends Alpha` then it will use the beta version of `reset()`. But here we want to use the super and where it will be use.

Comment: `interface` does not allow implementation.  What you are looking for seems to be `trait`s in scala?

Comment: Possibly you should use `abstract class` instead

Comment: Like `Alpha.super.reset();` That's exactly the way you refer to it.

Comment: @vikeng21 "default" was introduced in Java 8. That is why the interface contains code.

Comment: You can in fact provide default implementation in Java 8.

Comment: @community downvoting without comments is conter-productive, we have a new user here

Comment: For example if we wants to use the beta version of reset() method, then we have to extend one of them two interfaces,,,for example : 'interface beta extends alpha' then it will use the beta version of  "reset()". but here we want to use the super and where it will be use.

Comment: @Philipp Claßen thanks did not about know this feature in Java 8. have removed comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for calling the default method implementation that could be coming from two different interfaces uses the name of the interface followed by `.super` as follows:

```
class MyClass implements Alpha, Beta {
    public void reset() {
        Alpha.super.reset();
        Beta.super.reset();
    }
}
```

This implementation of the `reset()` method calls the default method implementations from both interfaces.

Comment: When i trying to apply the above code what you write in answer than i get error, that `MyClass cannot implement reset` .Plz edit your answer.

Comment: @ManoharKumar That's because the method is supposed to be public.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling your code would produce an error:

> java: class MyClass inherits unrelated defaults for reset() from types alpha and beta

because the compiler cannot select a declaration to use in this conflicting situation.

[Here is an article for your reference.](http://www.lambdafaq.org/how-are-conflicting-method-declarations-resolved/)